# have any way to get Latitude and Longitude without GPS receiver and CellID

Tags: blackberry

I want find Latitude and Longitude of Mobile user but clint mobile not support GPS and also deny to use GPRS to access.if you have idea to fetch latitude and longitude without internal GPS system in mobile and cell ID.please any one help me...

Answer (score 0):

Nope, that's not possible. You can make a guess based on the client's IP address, but that's only good for locating the country (e.g. I often get located up to 300 km beside my actual location).

The only remaining option (if GPS is out, CellID is out, and since IP location is unreliable) is to ask the user for the real-world (mailing) address and check where that is - but that won't tell you where the user is *right now*.

Comment: Actually you can send your wifi info to google and it will tell you your lat-long, see method here (the service accepts not only cellid but also wifi only): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2754338/cell-triangulation-on-blackberry