# Getting the MCC and MNC for the operator on blackberry

Tags: blackberry

I am trying to get the MCC and MNC for the blackberry device. I am using this code:

```
int code = RadioInfo.getCurrentNetworkIndex();
int mcc = RadioInfo.getMCC(code);
int mnc = RadioInfo.getMNC(code);
String mccS = Integer.toString(mcc);
String mncS = Integer.toString(mnc);
```

I am getting values, byt when searching for the right values on the internet, I found that the MCC and MNC differ from the ones I obtained in this code. For example for the operator alfa in lebanon, I should obtain:

Mcc = 415 and MNC = 1

I am obtaining:

Mcc = 1045 and MNC = 1

Why Is that happening? Is this the right way to get the MCC and MNC? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you get mcc by using

```
String mcc = Integer.toHexString(RadioInfo.getMCC(RadioInfo.getCurrentNetworkIndex()));
```

Comment: Will I need to use Integer.toHexString(GPRSInfo.getMCC()) some like that or GPRSInfo.getMCC() will work. Please let me know.

Answer (score 3):

In my experience it's quite messy on BB. Based on experiments accross different networks and devices, we use

```
// manual says MCCs can be identified as either 260 or 26F; actually for us it is decimal so we convert it to hexa
// this replaceAll "f" stuff is strange, but seems to work: MNC==1F becomes 1 which nicely matches RadioInfo.getMNC(RadioInfo.getCurrentNetworkIndex());
int mcc =  Integer.parseInt(TextUtils.replaceAll(Integer.toHexString(GPRSInfo.getCellInfo().getMCC()),"f", ""));
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to convert the number.

The MNC and MCC will be returned as decimal numbers, whereas MCCs and MNCs will be listed as hexadecimal numbers. For example, a BlackBerry smartphone operating on the AT&T® mobile network will return MCC=784 (hex 310) and MNC=896 (hex 380).

http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/800332/1467358/How_To_-_Determine_the_MCC_and_MNC_of_the_current_network.html?nodeid=1467359&vernum=0