# get current lat long without GPS in blackberry storm 2

Tags: blackberry, gps, blackberry-storm

i m working with the application which are needed to get current lat long of user .
in our area GPS is not working so how to get lat long without gps system

Answer (score 1):

You can send your wifi and/or cellid info to google (or to [RIM's own service](http://devblog.blackberry.com/2011/09/wifi-geolocation-launch/) but that is still alpha quality) and it will tell you your lat-long, see method here:
[Cell triangulation on BlackBerry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2754338/cell-triangulation-on-blackberry)

Comment: after getting cell id my URL becomes "http://www.opencellid.org/cell/get?key=myapikey&mcc=404&mnc=5&cellid=60217&lac=260" and still get lat and long 0.0 .. i m using wi-fi in my device so how to get wifi id for send request .?

Comment: My Responce : <rsp stat="ok">
<cell lat="0.0" mcc="" lon="0.0" cellId="" nbSamples="0" mnc="" lac="" range="50000"/>
</rsp>

Comment: opencellid doesn't support wifi location; check my answer for services that do support that