# Unable to retrieve correct location using CellID in blackberry

Tags: blackberry, geolocation, gsm

Hello I wrote the below code to retrieve the cellId, lac, mcc, mnc. And when i retrieved these i used the below link to retrieve latitude and longitude:  [opencellid](http://www.opencellid.org/cell/get?mcc=405&mnc=25&cellid=45963&lac=17143) But the location is 70 kms away from where i am. Is there any alternative to get a correct location. I tried this on 4 Network providers namely: TATA Docomo(70 Kms variation), Airtel(30Kms variation) and i didnt retrieved longitude, latitude for uninor and vodafone. Please help me out

Comment: hav u solve ur problem in this question? I'm also need solution for this question. Could u help me?

Comment: using opencellid is not reliable. There is an class called Criteria() in bb. Use it u will find many code samples in net. All the best

Comment: Refer to the second link in the first answer

Comment: My device is 9800 os 6.0. it has gps. I execute the GPSDiagonstic pgm. if i disable the gps. it tell provider unavaiable for that criteria.

Comment: at what code u r used for get latitude when user not allowed gps ?

Comment: I don't have any gps in my mobile. You should have gprs activated on your sim card if you are to use without gps. Make sure that your service provider is providing the bb gprs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cell ID should give you the location of the cellsite the phone is communicating with, not the phone location itself as far as I know. If you want the phone location you can use the [BlackberryLocationProvider](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/gps/BlackBerryLocationProvider.html), for best precision use Autonomous mode, for fast fixes use Cellsite (which should use a triangulation of a few cell towers to determine your location). You can find more information and some code samples [here](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Location-APIs-Start-to-finish/ta-p/571949).

Comment: I don't have GPS in my mobile that's why i am trying to use CellID. Please provide some help in this case. Thank you

Comment: You should still be able to use the Cellsite option - it does not use satellite (gps), just cell towers. Basically you want to pass GPSInfo.GPS_MODE_CELLSITE to the criteria when creating the provider. take a look at the second link I posted, it describes this option. You can also use what ber4444 suggested.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use either Google Gears which is more accurate (see [Cell triangulation on BlackBerry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2754338/cell-triangulation-on-blackberry/2758149#2758149)), or [RIM's new service](http://devblog.blackberry.com/2011/09/wifi-geolocation-launch/) which might still be beta quality. Note that both of these services I mentioned support adding wifi data to cellid which will give much better results.