# BlackBerry: Reasons why GEOLOCATION_MODE_WLAN might not be available?

Tags: blackberry, geolocation, gps, wifi

Why could GEOLOCATION_MODE_WLAN not be available?

I am using a BlackBerry Bold 9780. The wifi on my device is turned on. Here are 5-10 wifis around and I am even connected to one. I sometimes got a Wlan-fix but I can't get any for a while.

```
LocationInfo.isLocationSourceAvailable(LocationInfo.GEOLOCATION_MODE_WLAN);
```

Returns *false*.

I just noticed that `GEOLOCATION_MODE_WLAN` is quiet a new thing in Blog: Please refer this [blog-post](http://devblog.blackberry.com/2011/09/wifi-geolocation-launch)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it going by setting a `maxAge` when setting the `LocationListener` (was -1 => default before):

```
myLocationProvider.setLocationListener(new LocationListenerImpl(), 600, 300, 30);
```

I can reproduce this, but is does not make any sense to me... And it does not work everytime. Whatever I give up on this...

- EDIT -

It might also not be supported by your carrier.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Google's service instead which is much more reliable and accurate and also accepts wifi data. See here: [Cell triangulation on BlackBerry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2754338/cell-triangulation-on-blackberry)

Comment: Not exactly an acceptable answer to the question but a great and helpful link/idea. Thanks :)